# Pointer changing after function call

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

Here is some simple points about my problem;

- Using XCode 6.0.1 if that matters, llvm 6.0 with no optimizations (DEBUG)
- This is happening on a separate thread launched with;

  ```
  self.ioThread = [NSThread.alloc initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(initData) object:nil].autorelease;
  ```
- Not using ARC (should not matter)
- First code;

  ```
  if (_updatedAt) // A simple C function call
      data[@"updatedAt"] = RFC3339DateString(_updatedAt);
  ```
- `RFC3339DateString` function;

  ```
  NSString* RFC3339DateString(NSDate* date) {
      if (!date || ![date isKindOfClass:NSDate.class]) return nil;
      NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = NSDateFormatter.new.autorelease;
      NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"].autorelease;

      [rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
      [rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
      [rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
      return [rfc3339DateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; // point of crash.
  }
  ```

So, on the line I marked "point of crash", It says;

`-[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdc2870`

There are couple strange things in this situration I cannot solve;

- On the first line of the function, I'm already type-checking `date` object.
- On debugger, when I say `po date` and `p date`, these are the results are I get;

  ```
  (lldb) po date
  stamp

  (lldb) p date
  (NSDate *) $11 = 0x7fdc2870 @"stamp"
  ```
- And when I go to the function calling `RFC3339DateString` function and say `p _updatedAt` and `po updatedAt`;

  ```
  (lldb) p _updatedAt
  (NSDate *) $12 = 0x7fd88a10 class name = __NSDate
  (lldb) po _updatedAt
  2014-09-27 06:37:33 +0000
  ```

I cannot understand how did the pointers changed in the middle of the way. Does anybody understand the situation?

Screenshot 1; http://cl.ly/image/1n1l1E1i2a3y

Screenshot 2; http://cl.ly/image/2A0s3S2J0S1P

Assembly Code around the code I'm calling RFC3339DateString function; http://pastie.org/private/e7xzc3ntfz0p0d95g5hzw

Comment: the autorelease is the culprit... and also causes the error message. Whenver you get such things like NSCFString unrecognized selector sent... when you are not using an NSString, check if the object isn't released...

Comment: @Volker, object is still there :( you can see the result of `po _updatedAt` above. But autoreleasepool definitely might be the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect `_updatedAt` is being overwritten. Sometimes it contains an `NSDate` and sometimes an `NSString`. Add a watchpoint to see where it's being written to.

Also, you should never return `nil` from `RFC3339DateString()` as that will cause an exception within `[NSMutableDictionary addObject:forKey:]`.

Lastly you don't need so many quotes in that date formatting string, just around `'T'` and `'Z'`.

Comment: thanks for suggestions, code is a bit dirty in those points. As I have said, when I go one frame out in debugger and check _updatedAt, it's still there as it should be. It's even there when it reaches RFC3339DateString function, but the pointer put on date parameter of  the function is changing in the middle (it looks like).

Comment: @FurkanMustafa With respect to my first sentence, where you check that `date` is an `NSDate` instance and return early, it would never get to the last line of that function, so it's almost as if it's an `NSDate` when first hitting the function but changes to an `NSString` while the function is executing.  Due to thread scheduling I would expect this error to be intermittent.

Comment: Ah actually you (and @Volker) are right, `_updatedAt` is definitely overwritten, and the old one got released (on another thread) while RFC3339DateString didn't finish yet, and it had old pointer. Now that makes sense.